# Executing transaction: failed

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda, spyder

I was trying to update spyder 3.3.2 by conda update spyder command on my windows 10 but it gives me error

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.4.10-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

Comment: i solved this problem by right clicking Anaconda Prompt by selecting "Run As Administration"and then running the command i want to execute ,just type conda comand for installing or updating  packages or spyder or python or anaconda navigator after opening "Run As Administration"

Comment: it works for windows 10 users